# execute a deletion command in sublime text's build command?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

So I am using sublime text 3 and I have the following build system to remove the existing executable then build then run, but it seems deletion command is not working. So is there a way to actually do this command in the build system?

```
{
 "cmd": ["del", "${file_base_name}","&", "g++", "${file}", "-std=c++11", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}", "&", "start", "cmd", "/c", "${file_base_name} & echo. & pause"],
 "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
 "working_dir": "${file_path}",
 "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
 "shell": true,
 "encoding":"utf-8",
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem by myself. In win32 you should delete "${file_base_name}.exe rather than "${file_base_name}.

hope this can help others.